# on-third, and two-thirds column wont align to each other

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

Ive been using skeleton framework and here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets_skeleton/skeleton.css">
</head>
<body class = "container sixteen columns" style = "height : 400px; border: solid 1px;">
    <div class = "two-thirds column" style = "height: 200px; border: solid 1px; float: left;">

    </div>
    <div class = "one-third column" style = "height: 200px; border: solid 1px; float: right;">

    </div>

</body>
```

im getting this output :

[image]

while my expected output is something like this :

[image]

Help please, Thank you  :)

Comment: show us the CSS content of "stylesheets_skeleton/skeleton.css"

Comment: i got it, i added position : absolute; to the style of the left div. anyways thanks @PravinS :)

Answer (score 0):

**This may Help you**

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets_skeleton/skeleton.css">
    </head>
    <body class = "container sixteen columns" style = "height : 400px; border: solid 1px;">
    <div style="width:100%; float:left;">
        <div class = "two-thirds column" style = "height: 200px; border: solid 1px; float: left;">

        </div>
        <div class = "one-third column" style = "height: 200px; border: solid 1px; float: right;">

        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry this did no work, thank you though. i got it working by adding position : absolute; to the left div.

Comment: you might wanna edit it and try what i did so i could accept it as the correct answer, maybe others will find this helpful. thanks

Comment: did you used my code in your required place i think you must use it it works fine bro.

Answer (score 0):

Add style in 'columns' `display:-webkit-box` and remove `float` styles from child of 'columns'/'sixteen' class. And done. :)